# Bitnami codes in instant articles! how to fix it?

Tags: html, wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, facebook-instant-articles

My website is hosted in AWS using the WordPress certified by Bitnami. The problem is whenever an author posts an article, it converts it into an instant article with some warnings. These warnings include the Bitnami banner codes. The Bitnami banner is hidden in the web pages using the CSS. but is not hidden from RSS feeds. Is there any way to hide the Bitnami codes in instant articles?

For example, this is the code of the instant articles with the warning:

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can remove the Bitnami banner by running these commands in the instance where WordPress is installed

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --disable_banner 1
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/bninfo/#how-to-remove-the-banner

If this does not solve the issue, then open the files below with a text editor and remove their content and restart Apache:

- /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf
- /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner-substitutions.conf

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/#cant-you-remove-the-bitnami-banner

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instant Articles engineer here,

Per [Facebook Instant Articles markup referenced docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/image) and defined markup structure, we don't support images within any container, like:

- in anchors
- in paragraphs
- enclosed into divs and any other
  container